# Weird-looking Registry entry under HKCU\Software\Classes (is it a virus)?

Tags: windows, virus, malware

I wanted to set Photoshop as my default image viewer (need a workaround because Windows doesn't recognize it), so I have to edit my Registry. In the tutorial on the official Adobe website, they say to navigate to the location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\Photoshop.exe\shell\open\command
```

But the only location with `Application` I found was this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppXak1hygz1tpjjnxhr1pwtcgnkpr24r5e7\Application
```

Doesn't this path look suspicious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not assume that everything with a bizarre name is a virus!** For example, the items in `\Windows\WinSxS` are *all* named with non-English character sequences, but they're critical to your system's health.

Subkeys under `HKCU\Software\Classes` that start with `AppX` belong to Windows Universal (or Metro, if you like) apps, the kind you get from the Windows Store. I have them on my Windows 8 machine, and they appear in a fresh install of Windows 10. You can see which app is which by opening the `Application` subkey and looking at the `ApplicationName` entry.

The `AppX` name fragment also decorates other components related to  those apps, like the `Get-AppxPackage` PowerShell command.

Don't worry, the presence of such Registry entries does not mean you have a virus.

---

Also, you might find the Registry settings you're looking for under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications`. Finally, there are [other Registry ways](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-image-editor-windows-8) to change the default programs that don't use that specific path.

Comment: Upvoted for the first/bold sentence :P

Comment: Also, one should use the default programs control panel, or `ftype` and `assoc` commands, in preference to manual registry editing. `assoc` assigns an extension to a named file type and `ftype` assigns a named file type to a default program.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yea you are right. But today somehow  TWINUI appeared somehow (windows didnt updated something and I haven't installed something)  in the "open as" tab and changed it self as a default viewer for almost everything. In addition to that I have only noticed this change because I got a weird class error while trying to open an image file. And that was too suspicious, I thought. @Bob As I said windows doesnt regonize it so I coulnt choose it. After googling it I have found the adobe instructions.+1 Good to here about the commands didnt knew them.